# adding innerHTML and style to part of a string in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to extract part of a string value that includes the Trade Mark in react and apply className or inline style so i can change the style, but the result i am getting from this code is [object object]

```
const dataTm = <span style={{ border: '2px black solid' }}>™</span>

const changeFormat = (item) => {
  const replaceTm = item?.name.replace('™', `${dataTm}`)
  return ReactHtmlParser(replaceTm)
}
const menu = () =>{
return(
<Link>
 {item?.name.includes('™') ? changeFormat(item) : item?.name}
<Link>
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#replace` returns a *string* - it converts everything what passed in into a *string* as well. And if you try to convert an object (and this is what `JSX` is - an object), you will get `[Object object]` in return.

You have to slightly modify your code, the most important difference is to change the `dataTm` variable to a string, so it can be properly understood by the `String#replace` function.

```
const item = {
  name: 'abc™abc',
};

export default function App() {
  const dataTm = "<span style='font-size:32px;color:red'>™</span>";

  const changeFormat = (item) => {
    const replaceTm = item?.name.replace('™', dataTm);
    return ReactHtmlParser(replaceTm);
  };

  return (
    <div>{item?.name.includes('™') ? changeFormat(item) : item?.name}</div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-frost-5fk6je?file=/src/App.js

The code above and in the codesandbox it's just a minimal example. In your code sample you should just wrap `dataTm` with quotes and adjust the styles a bit and it should work properly.

Comment: i used what you suggested and i get undefined value for const replaceTm ``` const dataTm = '<span style=font-size:32px;>™</span>'  const changeFormat = (item) => {
  const replaceTm = item?.name.replace('™', dataTm)
  console.log(dataTm)
  console.log(replaceTm)
  return ReactHtmlParser(replaceTm)
}```

Comment: from my understanding .replace just change a string with a new string, i am not sure why we use dataTm just by itself there

Comment: @Afra Hmm, it works well for me. Please check the updated codesandbox.